# SwashBuckle-Swagger-ui 2: Dictionaries are not interpreted (AdditionalProperties are not recognized)

Tags: swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using Swashbuckle 5.6 which is using Swagger-UI 2.2. Unfortunately the dictionaries are not interpreted because Swagger-ui doesn't interpret the additionalProperties of a Map.

The result of swagger-ui is :

```
MyNamespace.Models.DictionaryErrorModel {
                  ValidationErrors (inline_model, optional, read only)
```

}
   inline_model {} // The inlimodel is empty!!!

I want to customize swagger-ui in order to fix this bug. Could anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Dictionary rendering was added in Swagger UI 3.x, IIRC. Try the latest version of Swagger UI.

Comment: Following up on @Helen comment, if you use `swashbuckle` you probably don't know how to use the latest Swagger UI... If that is the case try with Swagger-Net: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net/  _ that is my fork of swashbuckle but I'm using the latest and  greatest of all dependencies.

Comment: @HelderSepu Thanks but i don't want to bring Swagger-UI 3 in Swashbuckle. I just want to fix Swagger-UI 2. I've noticed that the team of Swagger-UI included code of Swagger-js, but for now i could'nt fix the bug in the signature.js file.

Comment: @IssaDawaji in that case just don't use Swagger-UI 2 use the 3.x version, your issue has been fixed there

Comment: @HelderSepu  Apparently the Swagger-UI 3.x version contains bugs and some features are still missing.

Comment: @IssaDawaji Because Swagger-UI 2.x does not have any bugs or missing features?